# Get columns by string from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

`raw` is a `data.table` and the following code works:

```
raw[,r_responseTime] #Returns the whole column
raw[,c_filesetSize]  #Same as above, returns column
plot(raw[,r_responseTime]~raw[,c_filesetSize]) #draws something
```

Now I want to specify these columns from a string, so for example:

```
col1="r_reponseTime"
col2="c_filesetSize"
```

How can I now achieve the same as above while referencing the columns by the string?

```
raw[,col1] #Returns the whole column
raw[,col2]  #Same as above, returns column
plot(raw[,col1]~raw[,col2]) #draws something
```

Does not work, of course because I need some kind of "dereferencation". I didn't know what to search in the help and the internet, so sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: In addition to the answers, try `with=FALSE`. Also, see FAQs 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: `with=FALSE` does not seem to work with the `by` argument, any solution for that?

Comment: Well, actually, a vector of strings works out of the box in the `by` argument.

Comment: Man, this is a *really* annoying part of data.table... If you write it one way, it works with dataframes, and if you fix it for data.table, it fails for dataframes. Is there no general solution?

Comment: @naught101 I use standard base R `raw[[col1]]` for selecting a single column as a vector from a data.table where `col1` contains which one.  I don't see why people are trying to use data.table `[...]` for that.  The NEWS items explicitly recommend `[[` and `$` on data.table where whole columns are required as vectors. Maybe this advice needs to be added to `?data.table`.

Comment: @naught101 More annoying was that `DT[,1]`, `DT[,3:10]` and `DT[,colP:colW]` didn't work before. They all work now in recent versions to alleviate that annoyance. Without losing the convenience and power that `j` can be expressions of column names directly.

Comment: @Frank how is this a duplicate of a question asked later?

Comment: The dupe target has an answer by the package's author that is better maintained (eg, includes the `..x` notation). Looking around on meta, it seems like this sort of closure is regarded as okay https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It would be nice if you had provided a reproducible example, or at the very least shown what the column names of `raw` are and what `r_responseTime` and `c_filesetSize` contain. This being said, `get` is your function for dereferencing so give these a try:

```
raw[, get(col1)]
raw[, get(col2)]
plot(raw[, get(col1)] ~ raw[, get(col2)])
```

Comment: Thanks, exacttly what I was searching for!

Comment: How can I use `get` if I have 2 column names as strings? Sorry, actually `with=FALSE` does the trick...

Comment: Standard base R `[[` is perhaps easier for single column selections when the column name or number is held in `col1`: `raw[[col1]]`.

Answer (score 12):

A modern approach is to use `..`:

```
raw[ , ..col1]
```

`..` "looks up a level" to find `col1`.

---

An older, less preferred alternative is to use the `match()` function or `%in%` operator.

```
raw[, match(col1, names(raw)),with=FALSE]
```

Comment: Match is nice. I needed to use `with=FALSE` as in: `raw[, match(col1, names(raw)), with=FALSE]`

Answer (score 9):

If you have a vector of strings, you can use `mget`

```
cols = c("r_reponseTime", "c_filesetSize")
raw[, mget(cols)]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer!! This is the only thing that worked for me (more specific situation) and I was searching a good 30 min before anyone mentioned `mget`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately "get" can be problematic!
See example below:

```
m = 100
x1 = sample(c("cat", "dog", "horse"), m, replace=TRUE)
y1 = rnorm(m)
fill1 = sample(c("me", "myself", "dude"), m, replace=TRUE)
df = data.frame("x"=x1, "y"=y1, "fill"=fill1)
dt = data.table(df)
```

get does not work!

```
y = "y"
dt[ , get(y)]
```

get works!

```
yCol = "y"
dt[ , get(yCol)]
```

works always, but it's not pretty!

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("values = dt[ ,",  y, "]")))
eval(parse(text = paste0("values = dt[ ,",  yCol, "]")))
```