# Referencing a data.table column by pattern

Tags: regex, r, data.table

I am attempting to plot multiple data tables that share a column name pattern using a function. Below are two sample tables:

```
dt1 = data.table(date=seq(as.Date("2015/06/20"), as.Date("2015/06/29"), by= "day"),
             ppp_min = rnorm(10), ppp_mean = rnorm(10), ppp_max = rnorm(10))
dt2 = data.table(date=seq(as.Date("2015/06/20"), as.Date("2015/06/29"), by= "day"),
             qqq_min = rnorm(10), qqq_mean = rnorm(10), qqq_max = rnorm(10))
```

And a sample plot function:

```
plt <- function(dt,code) {
min <- paste(code, '_min',sep='')
plot(dt$date, dt[,get(min)])
}
plt(dt1,ppp)
plt(dt2,qqq)
```

The function allows to specify the data table to plot. The "code" in the function is used to apply relevant titles and write file names but coincidentally matches the variable in the column names. This is an application of [Get columns by string from data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864055/get-columns-by-string-from-data-table?lq=1)

My question is: Is it possible to do a pattern match instead? I have tried to do this using `grep` and applying `eval()` and `quote()` as suggested in the question [pass column name in data.table using variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable-in-r?lq=1)

I have attempted doing something like:

```
plot(dt$date, dt[,grep("min",names(dt))])
```

My reasoning for attempting a pattern match is that I have multiple `colnames` I am plotting and the first solution seems recursive. In this instance the "code" matches the variable but what if it didn't and I still want to pattern match?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `plt <- function(dt, code) {
    plot(dt$date, unlist(dt[, paste0(code, '_min'), with = FALSE]))
} ; 
plt(dt1, 'ppp') ; 
plt(dt2, 'qqq')`

Comment: I think the only problem is the missing with=FALSE (shown in alistaire's comment). Alternately, `[[` like `plt = function(dt) plot(dt$date, dt[[grep("min",names(dt))]])`

Comment: You know you can also use `plot` inside `[` in "data.table", right? Like `dt1[, plot(.SD), .SDcols = c("date", grep("min", names(dt1), value = TRUE))]`.

Comment: @Frank, your suggestion seems to be the solution. I had attempted a variation of this but somehow missed this application. It answers the question thanks! I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank's suggested answer is the most straight forward. It was tested to plot large data tables with a higher level of complexity and worked! The simplified function that works with the sample tables is found below.

```
plt <- function(dt,code) {
plot(dt$date, dt[[grep("min",names(dt))]])
}
plt(dt1,ppp)
plt(dt2,qqq)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using data tables `%like%` function will get you what you want without needing to create a function.  Depending on what you're looking for here are several options:

```
plot(dt1[,.SD, .SDcols=names(dt1) %like% "date|_min$"])

dt1[,lapply(.SD, plot, date), .SDcols=names(dt1) %like% "_min$"]

code <- c("ppp", "qqq")
plot(dt1[,.SD, .SDcols=names(dt1) %like% sprintf("date|(%s)_min$", paste(code, collapse="|"))])
```