# Row operations on selected columns based on substring in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rowwise

I would like to apply a function to selected columns that match two different substrings. I've found this [post related to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370226/referencing-a-data-table-column-by-pattern) but I couldn't get an answer from there.

Here is a reproducible example with my failed attempt. For the sake of this example, I want to do a row-wise operation where I sum the values from all columns starting with string `v` and subtract from the average of the values in all columns starting with `f`.

*update:* the proposed solution must (a) use the `:=` operator to make the most of `data.table` fast performance, and (2) be flexible to other operation rather than `mean` and `sum`, which I used here just for the sake of simplicity

```
library(data.table)

# generate data
  dt <- data.table(id= letters[1:5],
                   v1= 1:5, 
                   v2= 1:5,
                   f1= 11:15,
                   f2= 11:15)

dt
#>    id v1 v2 f1 f2
#> 1:  a  1  1 11 11
#> 2:  b  2  2 12 12
#> 3:  c  3  3 13 13
#> 4:  d  4  4 14 14
#> 5:  e  5  5 15 15

# what I've tried
  dt[, Y := sum( .SDcols=names(dt) %like% "v" ) - mean( .SDcols=names(dt) %like% "f" ) by = id]
```

Comment: The desired output of `Y` is `-9, -8, -7, -6, -5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `melt` the dataset into 'long' format, by making use of the `measure` argument, get the difference between the `sum` of 'v' and `mean` of 'f', grouped by 'id', join `on` the 'id' column with the original dataset and assign (`:=`) the 'V1' as the 'Y' variable

```
dt[melt(dt, measure = patterns("^v", "^f"), value.name = c("v", "f"))[
         , sum(v) - mean(f), id], Y :=V1,  on = .(id)]

dt
#   id v1 v2 f1 f2  Y
#1:  a  1  1 11 11 -9
#2:  b  2  2 12 12 -8
#3:  c  3  3 13 13 -7
#4:  d  4  4 14 14 -6
#5:  e  5  5 15 15 -5
```

---

Or another option is with `Reduce` after creating index or 'v' and 'f' columns

```
nmv <- which(startsWith(names(dt), "v"))
nmf <- which(startsWith(names(dt), "f"))
l1 <- length(nmv)
dt[, Y := Reduce(`+`, .SD[, nmv, with = FALSE])- (Reduce(`+`, .SD[, nmf, with  = FALSE])/l1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`rowSums` and `rowMeans` combined with `grep` can accomplish this.

```
dt$Y <- rowMeans(dt[,grep("f", names(dt)),with=FALSE]) - rowSums(dt[,grep("v", names(dt)),with=FALSE])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the solution (a) must use the `:=` operator to make the most of `data.table` fast performance, and (2) it must be flexible to other operation rather than `mean` and `sum`, which I used here just for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Going to leave this answer up, though, since it may be helpful for somebody who does not need the additional functionality you added to the original question.

Comment: sure! Thanks again !